# Resume wget after canceled

Tags: wget

I am coping a website and `^c` canceled it and if I resume, it does the entire thing over again but does not copy it over because of the exiing dirs. I would like to resume the `wget -r` copy and ignore all of the already downloaded sites.

Comment: Or am I wrong and it already detects this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `--continue` flag to Wget to ask it to resume the existing download.

However, even in this scenario, Wget will still parse the pages and send a HEAD request for each file. It is not possible to avoid this due to various reasons that I outlined in this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185933/952658).

Answer (score 1):

man wget: 
-c,  --continue  resume getting a partially-downloaded file.